# How to properly multiply 2 matrices in this problem?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

This is my mult method:

```
public Matrix mult(Matrix otherMatrix) {
if(!colsEqualsOthersRows(otherMatrix)) // checks if Matrix A has the same number of columns as Matrix B has rows 
        return null;
    int multiplication[][] = new int[rows][columns];
    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < otherMatrix.columns; c++) {
            int sum = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < otherMatrix.columns; i++) {
                sum = sum + matrix[r][i]*otherMatrix.matrix[i][c];
                multiplication[r][c] = sum;
            }
        }
    }
return new Matrix(multiplication);
}
```

In the driver method, whenever there's a question that involves multiplying matrices it's either wrong or I get an error from the system.

i.e.

```
3BC-4BD //which is

B.mult(3).mult(C)).subtract(B.mult(4).mult(D));
```

This is the error.

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
>
> at lab1.Matrix. mult(Matrix.java:81)
> at lab1.Driver. main(Driver.java:128)
> ```

These are the matrices I'm using.

```
Matrix A = new Matrix(new int[][] {{1,-2,3},{1,-1,0}});
    Matrix B = new Matrix(new int[][] {{3,4},{5,-1},{1,-1}});
    Matrix C = new Matrix(new int[][] {{4,-1,2},{-1,5,1}});
    Matrix D = new Matrix(new int[][] {{-1,0,1},{0,2,1}});
    Matrix E = new Matrix(new int[][] {{3,4},{-2,3},{0,1}});
    Matrix F = new Matrix(new int[][] {{2},{-3}});
    Matrix G = new Matrix(new int[][] {{2,-1}});
```

This is my **Matrix** class:

```
public class Matrix { 
    int [][] matrix; 
    int rows, columns; 

    public Matrix (int[][] m) { 
        this.matrix = m; 
        this.rows = m.length; 
        this.columns = m[0].length; 
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner in the JAVA language so please excuse my ignorance. Please help!

Comment: the problem comes when you multiply matrices with different sizes, if you are taking values from matrix B you have to check the size of B and not from C.

Comment: How would I fix this issue in the mult method?

Comment: share your matrix code

Comment: The upper limit of the innermost loop should be the number of columns rather than otherMatrix.columns. Additionally, make sure that the resulting sum is assigned after the innermost loop, not within the loop.

Comment: @AxelKemper That fixed some of the cases, AE. Thanks! But the error still appears for  3BC-4BD, for example.

Comment: @LostSoul: Please update your question. Work through some textbook examples of matrix multiplication to check your code. Include tests to make sure that the matrix operands are actually compatible wrt multiplication. Consider upvoting helpful comments ;-)

Comment: @vmrvictor public class Matrix {
 
 int [][] matrix;
 int rows, columns;
 
 public Matrix (int[][] m) {
  this.matrix = m;
  this.rows = m.length;
  this.columns = m[0].length;
 }
 All of the other functions I created, like add, subtract, transpose, and scalar work perfectly. It's just this multiplication function that's going over my head haha.

Comment: @AxelKemper I think my reputation is too low for that haha I don't see an option to do so. I'm sorry :(

Comment: I THINK the question AE worked because matrix(A in this case) has less rows than otherMatrix.matrix(E). In the other cases, it's the opposite, which is messing things up I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that output of the matrix multiplication is as follow: `A(nXm) * B (mXk) = C (nXk)`

In your case: `B(2X3) * C(3X2) = Output(2X2)`

However your code define the output matrix with the dimension of the first one (as can be see here: `int multiplication[][] = new int[rows][columns];`)

In order to fix that try (add 2 small optimization as set the `multiplication[r][c]` outside the inner loop):

```
int multiplication[][] = new int[rows][otherMatrix.columns];
for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for(int c = 0; c < otherMatrix.columns; c++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < otherMatrix.columns; i++)
            sum += matrix[r][i]*otherMatrix.matrix[i][c];
        multiplication[r][c] = sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the new matrix is this.rows, otherMatrix.columns
and when multiplying you are checking twice otherMatrix.columns and I think is the second for the one that should be this.columns

```
 public Matrix mult(Matrix otherMatrix) {
    if(!colsEqualsOthersRows(otherMatrix)) // checks if Matrix A has the same number of columns as Matrix B has rows
        return null;
    int multiplication[][] = new int[rows][otherMatrix.columns];
    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < otherMatrix.columns; c++) {
            int sum = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
                sum = sum + matrix[r][i]*otherMatrix.matrix[i][c];
                multiplication[r][c] = sum;
            }
        }
    }
    return new Matrix(multiplication);
}
```